# Wildcard * named group (:name*) not working with $routeProvider Angular js v1.0.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am trying to do a wildcard (*) routing in Angular js through following code snippet:

```
$routeProvider.when('/something/:action/:id/:params*\/', {

  templateUrl : "/js/angular/views/sample/index.html",

  controller : 'SampleCtrl'

}).otherwise({

  redirectTo: '/something/all' //This exists in real code

});
```

**sample path: /#/something/details/201/1**

On calling this url it executes the otherwise method. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Named group (wild cards *) are supported for version 1.2 and on-wards. I was trying for 1.0.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$routeProvider` does not support standard regexp but it does support *named groups*:

> - path can contain named groups starting with a colon (:name). All characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.
> - path can contain named groups starting with a star (*name). All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.

So you should try

`$routeProvider.when('/something/:action/:id/:params/*rest'`

which will match `/#/something/details/201/1/whatever/you/say`

Comment: Would it match `/#/something/details/201/1/` and `/#/something/details/201/1`? I have a module called "Assets" and would like it to respond to something like `/#/public/assets` -- `/#/user/:id/assets` -- and simply `/#/assets`. Will `/#*/assets` match these AND will I be able to get `:id` as a routeParam?

Comment: No. You have to explicitely define a separate route including `:id`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know angularjs not support regular expressions.
You should look at the angular ui-router.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$routeProvider.when('/something/:action/:id/:params?,
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for this answer? Thanks!

Comment: it works either if the parameter exists or not. so it would work with /something/:action/:id/:params or /something/:action/:id/

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged, and likely to result in deletion flags – including explanation or commentary in your answers will help people learn, and make your answers more visible on search engines!