# Controller loads twice when wildcard path is unencoded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that resolves a wildcard `path` that represents the actual path of the application. For example, `url: '/{path:.*}'` where `path` is `abc/def/`. The `path` is built programmatically.

If I encode `path`, the state's controller executes once, as expected, but the URL ends up with the encoded path (i.e., I see `mydomain.com/abc%252Fdef%252F` instead of `mydomain.com/abc/def/`). However, if I *don't* encode it the controller runs twice.

Why is the controller running twice? What do I need to do to get a path like `abc/def/etc.../` to display unencoded in my browser?

See example. Clicking "Go" changes the state and the controller logs to the console twice if `path` is not encoded.

EDIT: Apparently it's a [known issue with ui-router.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2339) And the suggested workaround is to encode the path as I had mentioned.

```js
var app = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('abc', {
          url: '/{path:.*}',
          controller: function() {
            console.log('loaded');
          }
      });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.go = function() {
    
    // loads once
    //var path = encodeURIComponent('one/two/three/four/');
    
    // loads twice
    var path = 'one/two/three/four/';
    
    $state.go('abc', {path: path});
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="routerApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="go()">GO</button>
    <div class="container">
      <div ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The $routeProvider does not support standard regexp but it does
>   support named groups

[Angular restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607534/wildcard-named-group-name-not-working-with-routeprovider-angular-js-v1-0)

Comment: It's supported when in curly brackets: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters